# Unwind Returns null Object in Spring Mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, criteria

I want to group all documents in the collection rooms_booked by multiple fields ( startdate,enddate,user.id and house.id) but i'm getting an empty array when i use Unwind.

This is an example of the documents in the collection Rooms_booked :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f071b74140d397a78c9c726"
    },
    "startdate": {
        "$date": "2020-07-14T15:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "enddate": {
        "$date": "2020-07-16T11:15:00.000Z"
    },
    "house": {
        "$ref": "houses",
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08b"
        }
    },
    "user": {
        "$ref": "users",
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "5e60ff0167e87e569fafc15e"
        }
    },
    "room": {
        "$ref": "rooms",
        "$id": {
            "$oid": "5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08d"
        }
    },
    "created": {
        "$date": "2020-07-09T13:28:20.604Z"
    },
    "_class": "com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.RoomsBooked"
}
```

I tried with this function :

```
Aggregation  aggregate = newAggregation(
                unwind("house"),
                unwind("house.id"),
                match(Criteria.where("house.id").is(idHouse)),
                 sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created"),
                group("startdate","enddate").push("$$ROOT").as("roomsbooked"),
                project("roomsbooked").previousOperation()
                );

        AggregationResults<RoomsBookedDTO> groupResults = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregate, "rooms_booked", RoomsBookedDTO.class);
        List<RoomsBookedDTO> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();
        return result;
```

It returns empty array.

How can i fix this?

**EDIT** :

These are 3 documents from my collection

```
     {
        _id:5ee3a8b68caa2837ac3f04fc
        priceperday:48
        priceperdayweekend:0
        price:1764
        startdate:2020-06-22T15:00:00.000+00:00
        enddate:2020-06-27T11:15:00.000+00:00
        house:DBRef(houses, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08b, undefined)
        user:DBRef(users, 5e70bb248574d576731fc6d5, undefined)
        room:DBRef(rooms, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08d, undefined)
        created:2020-06-12T16:09:26.506+00:00
        modified:2020-07-06T15:04:42.962+00:00
        _class:"com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.RoomsBooked" 
        },
    
    {
        _id:5ee3a8b68caa2837ac3f04fe
        priceperday:48
        priceperdayweekend:0
        price:1764
        startdate:2020-06-22T15:00:00.000+00:00
        enddate:2020-06-27T11:15:00.000+00:00
        house:DBRef(houses, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08b, undefined)
        user:DBRef(users, 5e70bb248574d576731fc7t2, undefined)
        room:DBRef(rooms, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08d, undefined)
        created:2020-06-12T16:09:26.506+00:00
        modified:2020-07-06T15:04:42.962+00:00
        _class:"com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.RoomsBooked" 
        },
{
        _id:5ee3a8b68caa2837ac3f04fk
        priceperday:48
        priceperdayweekend:0
        price:1764
        startdate:2020-06-22T15:00:00.000+00:00
        enddate:2020-06-27T11:15:00.000+00:00
        house:DBRef(houses, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08b, undefined)
        user:DBRef(users, 5e70bb248574d576731fc6d5, undefined)
        room:DBRef(rooms, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08f, undefined)
        created:2020-06-12T16:09:26.506+00:00
        modified:2020-07-06T15:04:42.962+00:00
        _class:"com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.RoomsBooked" 
        },
```

**Output**

I Want to group the documents by the id of the user ,startdate and enddate.

```
{
 "user" : "5e70bb248574d576731fc6d5",
 "roomsbooked" : [
    { 
    _id:5ee3a8b68caa2837ac3f04fc
    priceperday:48
    priceperdayweekend:0
    price:1764
    startdate:2020-06-22T15:00:00.000+00:00
    enddate:2020-06-27T11:15:00.000+00:00
    house:DBRef(houses, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08b, undefined)
    user:DBRef(users, 5e70bb248574d576731fc6d5, undefined)
    room:DBRef(rooms, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08d, undefined)
    created:2020-06-12T16:09:26.506+00:00
    modified:2020-07-06T15:04:42.962+00:00
    _class:"com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.RoomsBooked" 
    },
    {
    _id:5ee3a8b68caa2837ac3f04fk
    priceperday:48
    priceperdayweekend:0
    price:1764
    startdate:2020-06-22T15:00:00.000+00:00
    enddate:2020-06-27T11:15:00.000+00:00
    house:DBRef(houses, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08b, undefined)
    user:DBRef(users, 5e70bb248574d576731fc6d5, undefined)
    room:DBRef(rooms, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08f, undefined)
    created:2020-06-12T16:09:26.506+00:00
    modified:2020-07-06T15:04:42.962+00:00
    _class:"com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.RoomsBooked" 
    }
 ]
},
{
    "user":"5e70bb248574d576731fc7t2",
    "roomsbooked":[
     {
    _id:5ee3a8b68caa2837ac3f04fe
    priceperday:48
    priceperdayweekend:0
    price:1764
    startdate:2020-06-22T15:00:00.000+00:00
    enddate:2020-06-27T11:15:00.000+00:00
    house:DBRef(houses, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08b, undefined)
    user:DBRef(users, 5e70bb248574d576731fc7t2, undefined)
    room:DBRef(rooms, 5efdf2a7fbe1ed5e11e1b08d, undefined)
    created:2020-06-12T16:09:26.506+00:00
    modified:2020-07-06T15:04:42.962+00:00
    _class:"com.guestnhousebackpfe.models.RoomsBooked" 
    } ]
  }
```

Comment: It is unclear why you want to `unwind` at all.     Your example is EJSON output, not "native" docs.  Please show us 3 docs as input docs (i.e. as db.yourCollection.find(), not as EJSON output) and the output you seek.

Comment: I tried to use unwind to get the id of the nested object.

Comment: Hmm.  OK.  What happens if you just do
`$group: {_id: { user: "$user", sd: "$startdate", ed: "$enddate"}}`
And if you can share,  please just do a `db.yourCollection.findOne()` so we can really see the structure.   You can blank out identifiers.